# Create custom rollup logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a custom rollup logic to apply to a query that pulls "sub-total" at different BOM levels (Bill of Materials). I've tried to use the rollup function with group by, but it doesn't pickup the correct rows in the rollup (See picture). For instance, row 3 should rollup should include rows 3,4,5 and 6. Row 5 (bom level 2) rollup should only include 5 and 6(bom level 3). Here's what I have so far. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE #BOM_ALL
(
 SORT_PATH VARCHAR(1000) ,
 BOM_LEVEL VARCHAR(12),
 PART_NO VARCHAR(125),
 COMPONENT_NO VARCHAR(125),
 PART_QUANTITY DECIMAL(18,5),
 COMPONENT_QUANTITY DECIMAL(18,5),
 HOURS DECIMAL(18,5),
 LOGIC_ROLLUP_RESULTS DECIMAL(18,5)
```

);

```
INSERT #BOM_ALL
VALUES
('650.5104',0,'650.5104','',1.00000,1.000000, 14.784, 122.084),
('650.5104~~600.1383',1,'650.5104','600.1383',1.00000,1.000000,0.20000,
0.20000),
('650.5104~~647.6004',1,'650.5104','647.6004',1.00000, 1.000000, 53.43299, 
96.57536),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~647.6008',2,'650.5104','647.6008',1.00000, 1.000000, 
38.29316, 43.14237),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~647.6009',2,'650.5104','647.6009',1.00000, 1.000000, 
4.84921, 5.09921),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~647.6009~~650.6005',3,'650.5104','650.6005',1.00000, 
1.000000, 0.25000, 0.25000),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~648.3304',2,'650.5104','648.3304',1.00000, 1.000000, 
4.82947,7.36961),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~648.3304~~648.3346',3,'650.5104','600.3346',1.00000, 
4.000000, 0.64749,2.58994),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~648.3305',2,'650.5104','600.3346',1.00000, 1.000000, 
2.54014,5.08028),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~648.3304~~648.3346',3,'650.5104','600.3346',1.00000, 
4.000000, 0.64749,2.58994),
('650.5104~~647.6004~~648.3310',2,'650.5104','600.3346',1.00000, 1.000000, 
1.61005,1.61005)

SELECT 
SORT_PATH,
BOM_LEVEL,
PART_NO,
COMPONENT_NO,
PART_QUANTITY,
COMPONENT_QUANTITY,
HOURS,
LOGIC_ROLLUP_RESULTS as ROLLUP_HOURS
FROM #BOM_ALL
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What makes you see rows 3 to 6 as a group?

Comment: Roll-up logic is not clear to me. Are you trying to roll-up at parent part_no level? On what logic you are trying to roll-up row 3,4,5 and 6?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding rollup.. If your query has `GROUP BY a,b,c WITH ROLLUP` then you get extra rows in the results as if all different values of c became null, plus as if all different values of b,c became null, plus as if all different values of a,b,c became null. Whatever you group by, sqlserver will summarise each variation from most specific all the way up to least. If you group by cube, you get all permutations of a,b,c being null

Comment: Hey Caius, thank you very much for clarifying that. Maybe I should have named the ROLLUP HOURS column as Total Hours instead. The logic I'm trying to create would, for example, group(rollup) rows 3 thru 6 into row 3, column ROLLUP HOURS, then group/rollup rows 6 into 5. Row 4 would actually stay the same (I made a mistake here) because its BOM_Level (2) is the same as row 5's. Following the logic, row 8 (BOM Level 3) rolls into row 7 (BOM Level 2). Same for rows 10 and 9. I hope this makes a bit more sense. Thanks